# Yii how to call function recursively

Tags: php, recursion, yii2, yii2-basic-app

How can I call recursively `test()`? I tried both ways and it didn't work.

```
namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\web\Controller;

class SiteController extends Controller {

    public function actionIndex() {

        $test= $this->test(5);

        }
        return $this->render('index');
    }

    private function test($res) {
        $test1 = parent::test(1);
        $test2 = $this->test(1);
    }

}
```

I tried with `$test1 = parent::test(1);` AND `$test2 = $this->test(1);`.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: From the other question posted, it looks like we are doing someone's homework

Comment: `$test2 = $this->test(1);` should call function test (recursively) in this class, and `parent::test` will call it in the parent class.

Comment: Of course you have this syntax error in there  extra `}` in the method `actionIndex`.  Which unless that is a typo for the question probably doesn't help you any.

Comment: Also calling `parent::test(1)` does not make much sense, since `test()` is private.

Answer (score -1):

Syntax error

```
public function actionIndex() {

    $test= $this->test(5);

    } //<--- this should not be here as it closes the actionIndex method
    return $this->render('index');
}
```

This will throw something like `unexpected T_RETURN` parse error.

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a96e987e62820c3a4b928ec5a3244b37ea1d08f3)

And it's

```
  <b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) in
```

Also you probably cant call the parents test method from the child because its  private and you can only access a private method from within the class that declares it.  Even when using `parent` you can't resolve the scope to it.  The only way I can think to call it is to use reflection (specifically ReflectionMethod) and then set the accessibility of it to.  That would be considered a pretty ugly hack though.

```
class foo{
    private function test($var){
        echo $var;
    }
}


class bar extends foo{
  public function actionIndex($var){
      $this->test($var);
  }

  private function test($var){
      $R = new ReflectionMethod(parent::class, 'test');
      $R->setAccessible(true);
      $R->invoke(new parent, $var);
      //$this->test($var); //recursive
  }
}

(new bar)->actionIndex('Hello from parent');
```

Output

```
Hello from parent
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/800bc829105c776007f4332e99e9dfa984ecf9fd)

The problem you will have with this is you need an instance of **parent** to invoke the method on, which you don't have and calling `new` you will lose any state of the child object. So any properties set in the child wont transfer, even if they are defined in the parent (unless they are set in the constructor etc.) This may or may not be acceptable.

To make it recursive is fairly easy just add, `$this->test()` in the child's method after the reflection part.  Of course that will produce an infinite loop, but whatever.